# Minimal length of non-contractible loops

Tags: general-topology, geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Not self-intersecting loops on a connected closed orientable smooth surface $S$ must have a minimal length not to disconnect it, e.g. the equators of a torus. "Not to disconnect" is - on such surfaces - the same as "not to be contractible", isn't it? So my question is:

> Given a metric on a surface $S$ as above, (how) can the minimal length $l$
>   of a non-contractible loop be calculated? Or at least estimated?

With which other geometrical properties of the surface (say its diameter) might $l$ be related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimal length of a non-contractible loop on a surface is known as the *systole*. See the Wikipedia articles *Systoles of surfaces*, *Introduction to systolic geometry*, and *Systolic geometry*. (Apparently, the topic is thoroughly covered in Wikipedia thanks to the efforts of Mikhail Katz). To the references listed there I would add *Metaphors in systolic geometry* by Larry Guth, available on his [homepage](http://math.mit.edu/~lguth/) in two versions.

The systole is usually estimated in terms of the square root of the area ($n$th root of the volume, for $n$-dimensional manifolds). But the diameter can also be brought into play, as in the paper [On the diameters of compact Riemann surfaces](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1977-065-02/S0002-9939-1977-0447556-8/) by Fwu Ranq Chang.

Note that some sources talk about shortest noncontractible loop, others about shortest closed geodesic. This is the same thing, because the shortest noncontractible loop is necessarily a geodesic.

Comment: Dear user67687 (whoever you are): thanks for this helpful collection of references. I have not imagned that this is such a popular subject!

Comment: Loewner's systolic inequality gives an *upper* bound for the systole. To be honest: I've been more interested in a *lower* bound.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement the fine answer given by @user67687, I just have a small correction to the original question: "not to disconnect" is not exactly the same as "noncontractible".  Thus, on a surface of genus 2 with the usual relation $a_1b_1a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1}a_2b_2a_2^{-1}b_2^{-1}=1$, the loop $a_1b_1a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1}$ separates (disconnects) but is noncontractible.

Since the OP noted that his interest is mainly in lower bounds for the systole, it may be worth pointing out a number of remarkable recent papers in this direction, and particularly the recent text by [Shotaro Makisumi](http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.2965).  See also the listing [here](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/sgtdirectory/news.html).