# Conditions for loops to be homotopic

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

I am looking for a list of necessary and sufficient conditions for two loops on a (compact connected orientable) surface to be homotopic that could be made into a purely combinatorial definition of homotopy in embeddable (but not necessarily embedded) graphs (esp. triangulations of the surface). Or is there no chance for such a definition because homotopy is an essentially continuous concept, and graphs are discrete?

1. If two loops [intersect transversally in exactly one point](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124542/probing-a-manifold-with-closed-curves) they are not homotopic to each other and not homotopic to a contractible loop.
2. If two loops - each on its own - disconnect the surface they are both contractible and thus homotopic to each other.
3. If two loops are [shorter than the systole](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335765/minimal-length-of-non-contractible-loops) of the surface they are both contractible and thus homotopic to each other.

(The latter corresponds to a trivial sufficient condition for two cycles of a triangulation to be homotopic: if they are triangles.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a classical combinatorial algorithm to decide if two loops on a surface are homotopic, originally described by Max Dehn in 1912.  For closed walks in arbitrary surface graphs, there is an efficient implementation of Dehn's algorithm that runs in $O(n+L+L')$ time, where $n$ is the number of edges in the graph and $L$ and $L'$ are the lengths of the walks.  For details, see my SODA 2013 paper with Kim Whittlesey: "[Transforming Curves on Surfaces Redux](http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/pubs/dehn.html)".